# Folder name with a \n

Tags: python, directory

I have a default folder called **\n**ormal however python detects the \n same with if i put extracted **\"**
I keep getting permission denied writing and assuming it is because of the missing \

\"`folder_normal = "F:\Extractor\normal"
folder_output = "F:\Extractor\Extracted\"`

Edit

With the \ \ or the r it changes the folder to `F:\\Extractor\\Extracted\\\\` what even with os.mkdir cannot find the folder

Comment: Try flipping all the \ to / that usually works for me.  If that works let me know and I'll write up a full answer.

Comment: That did it, i am trying now to fix a with open error of the same folder with permission denied but that is a different issue :P

Comment: I don't understand what exactly do you mean by "it changes". Can you please post the code that causes the issue?

Comment: https://github.com/bobthecooldad/Hac-tool-loader/blob/master/Loader.py

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python windows path slash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19065115/python-windows-path-slash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I write Python in windows and have to deal with paths, I simply use forward slashes instead of back slashes.  Sure, you can do proper escaping but it always turns into a hassle of errors it seems.  So, change all your

```
\
```

to

```
/
```

So in this case, write this:

```
folder_output = "F:/Extractor/Extracted/"
```

And you should be good to go!

Answer (score 2):

use raw format

```
folder = r"F:\Extractor\normal"
```

It's the best way to write paths because you don't need to worry about possible changes where you will miss another \a \b \n \t \v sign.

Alternatively you can use "/" instead of "\".

See: https://community.esri.com/blogs/dan_patterson/2016/08/14/filenames-and-file-paths-in-python
to find other solutions

Answer (score 0):

input an additional `\`

```
folder_normal = "F:\Extractor\\normal"
folder_output = "F:\Extractor\Extracted\"
```

Comment: you only need the two when they're followed by a `n` or a `t`, as these are special characters that need to be "escaped" (a newline and a tab, respectively)

Comment: You need two when they're followed by `n` or `t` or `a` or `b` or `f` or `r` or `v` or `x` or a number. The smart solution is to use a raw string literal instead of doubling your backslashes.

Comment: @Aran-Fey: or a `u`, or any other possible future extension to Python's GREP. You're right, this is not a good solution at all; no more than an ad hoc fix.