# Selecting lines from many csv files and creating new files

Tags: python, csv

I have folder with hundreds of csv files, with one row in every file containing country names. I would like to loop through all the files, select the lines with country name "FIN" and create new csv files from the selected lines.

This is how far I have gotten:

```
import csv
import glob

for filename in glob.glob('\directory\*.csv'):
with open(filename, 'r') as i, open('\directory_for_new_files\fin_{}'.format(filename), 'w') as o:
   r = csv.reader(i, delimiter=',')
   w = csv.writer(o, delimiter=',')
   for row in r:
      if 'FIN' in row[3] or 'flag' in row[3] :
          w.writerow(row)
```

The `"fin_{}'.format(filename)"` part seems to be the problem, since when I replace it with just a name (like 'testfile.csv') the script works, but of course with the problem that it constantly overwrites the same file. So how do I get the script to create a new output file for every input file?

Error message:

> with open(r'D:\Koko Suomen ihmispaineet\Ihmispaineet_26_10_2018\Global
>   fishing
>   watch\fishing_effort\daily_csvs_finland\fin_{}'.format(filename), 'w')
>   as o:
>
> IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('w') or filename: 'D:\Koko Suomen
>   ihmispaineet\Ihmispaineet_26_10_2018\Global fishing
>   watch\fishing_effort\daily_csvs_finland\fin_D:\Koko Suomen
>   ihmispaineet\Ihmispaineet_26_10_2018\Global fishing
>   watch\fishing_effort\daily_csvs\2012-01-01.csv'

Comment: Do your errors disappear when you use [the correct number of backslashes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19065115/2564301)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 Problems:

- wrong slashes: you need to use either

  - raw strings with backslashes `r"\somedir\somefi.le"` or
  - escape backslashes: `"\\somedir\\somefi.le"`
  - or use slashes instead - they "simply work": `/somedir/somefi.le`
- you forgot to specify `newline=""` when [writing the csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer)
- [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob) returns filenames with path - you only need the filenames.

---

Fixed example:

```
import csv
import glob

# create demo files
for k in "abc":
    with open("./{}.csv".format(k),"w") as f:
        f.write(k+",b,c,FIN,d\n")
        f.write(k+",b,c,not,d\n")
        f.write(k+",b,c,flag,d\n")


# import / read / create new files:
import os    

extract = {'FIN','flag'}

for filename in glob.glob('./*.csv'):
    _, fn = os.path.split(filename)                            # fix here
    with open(filename, 'r') as i, \
         open('./fin_{}'.format(fn), 'w', newline="") as o:    # 2 fixes here
        r = csv.reader(i, delimiter=',')
        w = csv.writer(o, delimiter=',')
        for row in r:
            if row[3] in extract:                              # improvement
                w.writerow(row)    


# test creation and content
for filename in glob.glob('./*.csv'):
    print(filename)
    with open(filename) as f:
        print(f.read())
    print("------------")
```

Output:

```
./a.csv
a,b,c,FIN,d
a,b,c,not,d
a,b,c,flag,d

------------
./b.csv
b,b,c,FIN,d
b,b,c,not,d
b,b,c,flag,d

------------
./c.csv
c,b,c,FIN,d
c,b,c,not,d
c,b,c,flag,d

------------
./fin_a.csv
a,b,c,FIN,d
a,b,c,flag,d

------------
./fin_b.csv
b,b,c,FIN,d
b,b,c,flag,d

------------
./fin_c.csv
c,b,c,FIN,d
c,b,c,flag,d    

------------
```