# Possible bug with os.path.join()

Tags: python

I'm having an incomprehensible error in my code.
os.path.join will work with all paths I try, except those started with t after 'RC4'. Here is an example:

```
>>> os.path.join('RC4\static\posts', '0.png')
'RC4\\static\\posts\\0.png'
>>> os.path.join('RC4\templates\posts', '0.png')
'RC4\templates\\posts\\0.png'
```

If I split the first string, it works:

```
>>> os.path.join('RC4', 'templates\posts', '0.png')
'RC4\\templates\\posts\\0.png'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows path in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953834/windows-path-in-python)

Comment: More specifically, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19065115/python-windows-path-slash

Comment: Also if you use a forward slash, it will work on Windows, Linux, MacOS. and you can use forward slash to join paths instead of os.path.join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\t` is a tab char sequence. Use raw strings to avoid these issues:

```
os.path.join(r'RC4\templates\posts', '0.png')
```

Comment: And I thought it could be a bug! :)

Comment: @Coder The recommendation by Alexey Larionov about `pathlib` is better, though.

Answer (score 3):

`\t` has a special meaning of TAB character (similarly to `\n` and other "escape" characters). That's why you're discouraged to manually use slashes in your path string.

You better use [`Path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#basic-use) class with `/` operator

```
from pathlib import Path
posts_path = Path('RC4') / 'templates' / 'posts'
img_path = posts_path / '0.png'
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because '\t` is a special character representing a Tab (2 or 4 spaces). To avoid it being interpreted in that way, you can escape it using a backslash, like so

```
os.path.join('RC4\\templates\posts', '0.png')
>>> 'RC4\\templates\\posts\\0.png'
```

Although, according to xcodz-dot (comment), in a future version of python, you should escape the slash before posts as well, because an error will be raised otherwise,
which also works in python 3.8.6:

```
os.path.join('RC4\\templates\\posts', '0.png')
>> 'RC4\\templates\\posts\\0.png'
```

Alternatively, you can place an 'r' in front of the string:

```
os.path.join(r'RC4\templates\posts', '0.png')
>> 'RC4\\templates\\posts\\0.png'
```

Comment: in the first block, escaping backslash before posts is necessary because upcoming python version will raise error for that

Comment: Thanks, I added it!